# Esper via JMS Examples

Tags: jms, esper

In the vague question department, has anyone every used Esper with JMS as an Input Adpater? If so, is there any sample code out there?

Comment: A two-sentence question with a single tag which has a total of 5 prior questions pretty much guarantees that this question will sink without a trace. Try elaborating and adding some more useful tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an example of ESPER with JMS (ActiveMQ or TIBCO) given by ESPER , download esper and you will find it in ESPER DIR/examples/servershell

Comment: Thanks very much for that tip. I did however find the servershell example quite heavy and decided to take a more lightweight JMS example and "plug it in" with Esper.